# how to have one itempointer serialize from 1 to n across the selected rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

as shown in the example below, the output of the query contains blockid startds from 324 and it ends at 127, hence, the itempointer or the row index within the block starts from one for each new block id. in otherwords, as shown below
for the blockid 324 it has only itempointer with index 10
for the blockid 325 it has itempointers starts with 1 and ends with 9

i want to have a single blockid so that the itempointer or the row index starts from 1 and ends with 25

plese let me know how to achive that and
why i have three different blockids?

**ex-1**
query:

```
select ctid 
from awanti_grid_cell_data agcd
where selectedsiteid = '202230060950' 
    and centerPointsOfWindowAsGeoJSONInEPSG4326ForCellsInTreatment IS NOT NULL
    and centerPointsOfWindowAsGeoJSONInEPSG4326ForCellsInTreatment <> 'None'

result:
|ctid    |
|--------|
|(324,10)|
|(325,1) |
|(325,2) |
|(325,3) |
|(325,4) |
|(325,5) |
|(325,6) |
|(325,7) |
|(325,8) |
|(325,9) |
|(326,1) |
|(326,2) |
|(326,3) |
|(326,4) |
|(326,5) |
|(326,6) |
|(326,7) |
|(326,8) |
|(326,9) |
|(327,1) |
|(327,2) |
|(327,3) |
|(327,4) |
|(327,5) |
|(327,6) |
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense to me. What is the real, underlying problem you are trying to solve here?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the point. The `ctid` is the physical address of a row in the table, and it is none of your business. The database is free to choose whatever place it thinks fit for a table row. As a comparison, you cannot go to the authorities and request that your social security number should be 12345678 - it is simply assigned to you, and you have no say. That's how it is with the physical location of tuples.

Very likely you are not asking this question out of pure curiosity, but because you want to solve some problem. You should instead ask a question about your real problem, and there may be a good answer to that. But whatever problem you are trying to solve, using the `ctid` is probably not the correct answer, in particular if you want to control it.